# Handling Exceptions with Return Values

Tags: java, playframework

I'm building an application in the Play Framework, and am facing a challenge in one of my function definitions. This isn't really a Play Framework question, but it applies to Play because `sbt compile` fails because of this error.

So I have this function in one of my classes:

```
private JSONObject getJsonObject(String url) {
    HttpResponse<JsonNode> response;

    try {
        response = Unirest.get(url).asJson();
    } catch (UnirestException e) {
        Logger.error("Failed to GET data. Connection string was: " + url);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response.getBody().getObject();
}
```

The reason I decided to catch the Exception within the function was that I didn't want my function to `throw` an exception. Because then, this `try-catch` needs to be done at multiple places where the call is made to this function. I can avoid that by putting a `throws UnirestExecption` but that would bubble up all the way across the entire function stack, all the way to class constructors.

However, with the current code, my IDE and `sbt compile` both tell me:

```
[error]: variable response might not have been initialized
```

How do I get out of this in this case? I can't seem to do a `new HttpResponse()` because the [class definition](https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-java/blob/3b461599ad021d0a3f14213c0dbb85bab7244f66/src/main/java/com/mashape/unirest/http/HttpResponse.java) looks too scary to me. I of course can't do another `Unirest.get()` because that will throw an exception of its own!

What's a neater way out?

Comment: What do you want your function to return when the `UnirestException` occurs?

Comment: @Marvin I never even thought about it! See my comment to the accepted answer. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you expect response to be if an exception is thrown?
If `response = Unirest.get(url).asJson();` throws an exception, your response object will be uninitialized.

You can either wrap the exception caught and rethrow it like:

```
private JSONObject getJsonObject(String url) {
    HttpResponse<JsonNode> response;

    try {
        response = Unirest.get(url).asJson();
    } catch (UnirestException e) {
        Logger.error("Failed to GET data. Connection string was: " + url);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return response.getBody().getObject();
}
```

or return some default value if GET request fails:

```
private JSONObject getJsonObject(String url) {
    HttpResponse<JsonNode> response;

    try {
        response = Unirest.get(url).asJson();
    } catch (UnirestException e) {
        Logger.error("Failed to GET data. Connection string was: " + url);
        return null;
    }
    return response.getBody().getObject();
}
```

Comment: Also, note that `null` is probably not the best thing to use as "default value".

Comment: Additional note, you don't want to log stack traces with `System.out`, because some day in the future you might want to switch to a different logger, like Slf4j and be suprised not seing any stack traces at all. Log your exceptions with loggers or do not log them at all.

Comment: I am _not_ using `System.out` to log error. What makes you say that? But that aside, I appreciate the advice! :-)

Comment: Actually I'm new to Java, and thought that program flow breaks when an Exception occurs. As such the thought of returning a value never crossed my mind. :P

Comment: @dotslash sorry, I had `e.printStackTrace();` in mind. I believe it uses standard error stream (not stdout), which might be intercepted by the logger and suppressed. This was the issue I had to struggle with when I was changiing logger from Log4j to Slf4j - `printStackTrace` simply didn't work. I never got into details of that, but the issue was there and I had to refactor all of those calls.

Comment: @dotslash yes, program flow breaks when exception occurs, but not if you `catch` it (:

Comment: Thank you! That was a very important eye-opener. So, how do we log exceptions with logger? Using something like (the default?) `toString()`?

Comment: @dotslash I'm unsure what `Logger` you are using, but usually there's an overloaded method that looks kinda like `error(Throwable)`, you should use this one to log exceptions. `Logger.error(e)` or `Logger.error("message", e)` will probably work for you (:

Comment: Also, this adds the flexibility of customizing how exceptions are logged (sometimes you can do it with configuration files)

Comment: I'm using the built-in Logger of the Play framework. It doesn't handle Throwables, from what I could find, so for now I'm using `Logger.warn(e.toString());`. I think it's okay for the time being. At least I won't lose exception messages. Thank you once more for the tip! :-)